# Loki's SmallObjAllocator of of memory

Tags: c++, c++-loki

```
#include "stdafx.h"                            //In order to use Visual C++

#include <iostream>
#include <Loki\SmallObj.h>                    //The header file to manage
                                              // smalls objects allocator

class MySmallObj : public Loki::SmallObjAllocator    //inherit from the base
                                                     //class SmallObjAllocator 
{
public:
    MySmallObj():SmallObjAllocator(sizeof(char), sizeof(long),0){};
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MySmallObj * premier = new MySmallObj;                                                      //declaring my object derived from smallobjallcator
    char * myChar = static_cast<char*>( premier->Allocate(1, true));            //calling allocate from my object and conveting the void pointer to char*
    premier.Deallocate(myChar, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

The loki library uses essentially generic programming in c++
I have got the code up there using Small object allocator of memory(Loki::SmallObjAllocator)
I m using visual c++ 2010

I get those errors:

```
  >  MyLoki.cpp
1>MyLoki.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Loki::SmallObjAllocator::Deallocate(void *,unsigned int)" (?Deallocate@SmallObjAllocator@Loki@@QAEXPAXI@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>MyLoki.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void * __thiscall Loki::SmallObjAllocator::Allocate(unsigned int,bool)" (?Allocate@SmallObjAllocator@Loki@@QAEPAXI_N@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>MyLoki.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall Loki::SmallObjAllocator::SmallObjAllocator(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0SmallObjAllocator@Loki@@IAE@III@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MySmallObj::MySmallObj(void)" (??0MySmallObj@@QAE@XZ)
```

Comment: Have you added the configuration to link to the libs?

Comment: Tempted to mark this as a duplicate of "what is an unresolved external symbol error and how do I solve it"..

Comment: your first question @EdChum is to know if I have linked the library to the
 compiler? Yes I did.

Comment: And it is not a duplicate, because i searched the on internet(for weeks) examples using Loki::SmallObjAllocator but they are not consistent or explicit. (I only found the boost one:  boost::object_pool ) @MarcoA.

Answer (score 0):

I have founded an answer to my first question.

```
#include "stdafx.h"                            //In order to use Visual C++

#include <iostream>
#include <Loki\SmallObj.h>                    //The header file to manage
                                              // smalls objects allocator

class MySmallObj : public Loki::SmallObjAllocator    //inherit from the base
                                                     //class SmallObjAllocator
{
public:
    MySmallObj():SmallObjAllocator(sizeof(char), sizeof(long),1){};  //the chunkSize < maxObjsize
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MySmallObj * premier = new MySmallObj;                                                      //declaring my object derived from smallobjallcator
    char * myChar = static_cast<char*>( premier->Allocate(1, true));            //calling allocate from my object and conveting the void pointer to char*
    premier->Deallocate(myChar, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

the errors of multiple

> unresolved external symbol

are because of SmallObj.cpp , of Loki that was not included to the project

for example of Loki::SmallObjAllocator, Loki::SmallObject [here](http://www.oocities.org/marco_corvi/games/loki/test/smallobj.cpp.txt)